# Dynamic Setting of WPF Control Properties

Tags: wpf, properties, dynamic, assign

I'd like to be able to set properties for various controls in my WPF application where I have the string name of a control and the string name of its type, but I don't know how to do it.  So far I have this:

```
( (TabItem)this.FindName( "tabPatient" ) ).IsEnabled = false;
```

I can iterate through a list of control names and set properties with just the string name of the control, but what I want is to be able to do it without having to perform an explicit hard-coded cast of the object type.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate WPF's [VisualTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx#two_trees) to find an element by name and set a property.

For example, using some helper classes found [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) you can say

```
foreach(var s in controlList)
{
    var ctrl = VisualTreeHelpers.FindChild<UIElement>(this, s);
    if (ctrl != null)
        ctrl.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

You don't really need to know the control type. All controls with an `IsEnabled` property are based off of `UIElement`, so just cast the control as a `UIElement` to modify it's `IsEnabled` property

Comment: Wow, Rachel, talk about comprehensive.  I like H.B.'s answer as it is a very simple way to do what I needed, but you really knocked it out of the park with your approach.  You took a micro aspect of a problem, and solved the macro implications.  Your approach is very helpful in solving my immediate issue, and is food for thought for a deeper understanding of WPF as I continue to learn.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @MikeMalter Glad you found it helpful :) I frequently want to find things in WPF's Visual Tree and got tired of copy/pasting the same methods into my code, so just wrote them all into my WPF Library

Answer (score 2):

The type does not really matter, right? All you need is a property, so you could do something like this:

```
var obj = FindName("name");
obj.GetType().GetProperty("IsEnabled").SetValue(obj, false);
```

Alternatively you could use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx), which does about the same thing:

```
dynamic dynObject = (dynamic)FindName("name");
dynObject.IsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: HB, thanks for your answers, really cool and helped me understand a little more what is going on.  It is a good answer, and got the results I wanted.  I did mark Rachel's answer as the answer to the question as her answer not only solved the immediate issue, but provided a framework for solving other WPF navigational issues.  Thanks again.